# ¿Se puede poner un if en los constraints de sql server?

Tags: mysql, condiciones, constraints

lo que busco hacer es crear una restricción en la tabla DESAYUNO con las siguientes columnas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que si la descripción del desayuno inicia con pan, el precio mínimo sea de 1.50
lo que hice es escribir la restricción de la siguiente forma:
if(DESC_DES = 'pan%')
PRECIO_DES>=1.50

Pero no se como usar el if de forma completa en sql, ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Y qué pasa si el precio del PAN% que trae la nueva fila es menor? Podrías probar con un trigger before insert or update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer un condicional de una forma que MySQL lo entienda como sentencia, podemos usar por ejemplo la sentencia `CHECK`.

- La sentencia `CHECK` se utiliza para limitar el rango de valores que pueden ser aplicados en una columna.
- Si se define una restricción `CHECK` en una columna, solamente permitirá ciertos valores para esta columna.
- Y además, puede limitar los valores en ciertas columnas basándose en valores de otras columnas de la fila.

Usando la sentencia `CHECK` y la siguiente consulta podemos hacerlo:

```
ALTER TABLE DESAYUNO
CONSTRAINT precioMinimo
    CHECK (DESC_DES = 'pan%' AND PRECIO_DES>=1.50)
```

De esta forma, alteramos la tabla **DESAYUNO**, creando un **CONSTRAINT** con el nombre que queramos, y comprobamos que la columna **DESC_DES** empiece por '*pan*' y la columna **PRECIO_DES** sea mayor o igual a *1.50*.